# GetAsync using Basic Authentication even though I specify Bearer

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, dotnet-httpclient, getasync

I have the below `GetAsync` which I'm trying to authenticate with a bearer token but I get a 403 response. When I look at the request headers I can see `Authorization: Basic YWJjOmRlZg==`

```
var client = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myendpoint.com/v2/")
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");
var httpResponseMessage = _myclient.GetAsync("instruments?country=US&type=BOND").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The token is valid. I confirmed that with Postman. I also hardcoded it into `AuthenticationHeaderValue` to ensure I had the correct token. I guess I assumed I was passing the bearer token incorrectly.

How do I get it to use Bearer authentication?

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to do to help here.  We have no idea how the API you are talking to works, or whether your token is valid, or whether the credentials given to generate that token allow you access to the resource you are trying to use.

Comment: Where is the token variable ?

Comment: I added some into to the question regarding the token.

Comment: @runnerpaul Given answers did solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Passing token to header (I am currently using this):

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

or something like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 403 Forbidden response is thrown by the server because it refuses to authorize your request. This probably means you are missing some claim or specific claim value in your bearer token.